# What's a good way to notate: "$a$ equals all real numbers except $1$ and $-3$"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I'm wondering if there is a nice way to denote "$a$ equals all real numbers except $1$ and $-3$" without having to just write out the title verbatim.

*edit for context for posterity*: I was given a 3x3 matrix with a variable $a$ in each of the entries with other numbers (eg. one entry was $a$ + $3$), and I was to find all the value of $a$ for which the matrix was invertible. I used the rule that the det(of a triangular matrix) = the product of the entries on the main diagonal and the fact that a matrix is invertible iff its determinant is not equal to $0$

Comment: I don't understand the close votes here. This is a reasonable question, and is about maths...

Comment: Is $a$ a set of real numbers?  or is it an element of a set of real numbers.  The sentence "$a$ equals all real numbers except $1$ and $-3$" means that $a$ is a set of numbers, but the accepted answer seems to indicate that $a$ is supposed to be an element of that set.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: It would also be useful if you could explain  the context in which this question arises.  In a calculus class, where I am trying to describe the domain of a function as a collection of open intervals, I might write one thing; in a course on naive set theory, I might write something else.  There are numerous notations which might apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a \in \mathbb R - \{-3, 1\}$. It's also completely fine to write it in prose, like "a is a real number not equal to $1$ or $-3$." This is often preferable to writing it symbolically.

Comment: Thank you! This cleared things up :))

Comment: Glad to help out!

Comment: alt: $a \in \{r ~: ~r \in \mathbb{R}, ~r \neq -3, ~r \neq 1\}.$

Comment: Use the “setminus” symbol for this: $\Bbb R\setminus\{-3,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this as $a\in \{-3,1\}^c$

Comment: Along these lines, I would much prefer “$a\notin\{-3,1\}$”.

Comment: But then it is not clear that $a$ should be real (and not complex).